# Understanding pure nash strategy for general sum game

Tags: proof-verification, game-theory, algorithmic-game-theory

**Given a general sum game with the cost function**

$A = \begin{bmatrix} 2000 & 0 & 2000 \\
1000 & 100 &  1000 \end{bmatrix}$

$B = \begin{bmatrix} 400 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 400 \end{bmatrix}$

**$A$ is the cost matrix for player 1. $B$ is the cost matrix for player 2.**

Each player would like the lowest cost (think about the number as fuel usage)

My question is, would strategy pair **row 1, column 2** constitute a nash equilibrium of the game?

According to the definition of nash equilibrium for general game, a strategy pair is a nash equilibrium if no player gains anything by deviating from his current strategy.

In our case, player 1 definitely do not wish to deviate from the lowest cost of the game. Player 2 may deviate to **column 3** (to pick the other 0 fuel cost) but he has no incentive to do so.

But suppose I am player 1 and I pick row 1. But player 2 can pick column 2 or 3 yielding the same cost. Then I have a 50% 50% chance to either have the lowest cost in the game or the highest cost in the game. Would such a strategy violate the definition of nash equilibrium? Would such a strategy violate the no-regretness of nash equilibrium?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not quite clear to me what you mean by "such a strategy" in the last paragraph. You correctly quoted the definition of a Nash equilibrium, and the strategy pair "row $1$, column $2$" satisfies that definition. The fact that a player would be adversely affected by another player deviating from her strategy is irrelevant.

Comment: ok good to have that clarified thanks but it is sad you are like the only game theory guy on MSE doing game theory

Comment: @FenceJumper: I absolutely agree! Not just answering but also asking -- I've never understood why it's such an unpopular topic here.